# POST /rest/V1/carts/{cartId}/items isn't working when logged as customer

Tags: magento2, customer, api, rest-api

I'm trying to use all the `/carts/{cartId}` endpoint list in the magento rest API documentation with the cart ID I've recevied on POST `/rest/V1/carts/mine` but every time I'm getting a error

```
"message": "The consumer isn't authorized to access %resources.",
"parameters": {
    "resources": "Magento_Cart::manage"
}
```

Comment: can you post how you are posting data to the API call? It should be an error in your consumer token

Answer (score 0):

The error message implies that the customer's token might be expired or wrongly defined in `Authorization` key.
With that you can try to:

- Generate new customer access token using `/V1/integration/customer/token` endpoint and use the new access token in the Authorization key of your API POST request.